# Try to upgrade Magento 1.6 -> 1.7 via Connect

Tags: upgrade

I try to upgrade Magento 1.6.2 to 1.7 via Connect.

In the field "extension key to install" i paste: `connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest` but it nothing happens. Here's a screenshot: http://pbrd.co/16L4iw0

It looks like it want to upgrade to 1.6.2, but as it already is 1.6.2 so nothing change.

Do I use the wrong extension key? Where is my mistake?

The HowTo upgrade I use: http://www.expertmagentodevelopers.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-magento-1-6-1-to-1-7-0-using-connect-manager/

Comment: have you clicked on proceed button?
I've not done this actually, but what it shows are dependencies and you need to click "proceed" button in order to install the package

Comment: @Shathish Yes sure I clicked it. All I got is: "Already installed:..." in the greentext console.

Comment: @nbar, the url which provided by you is not opened, check once and update

Answer (score 2):

Why you didn't try to check if there are upgrade by clicking of the button "Check for Upgrades" and then apply the upgrades

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: After clicking Check for Upgrades I don't see any upgrade avalible: http://pbrd.co/16LmEwW

Comment: Maybe you deleted some content in the "var/packages" folder. There, is stored previous installation packages. Check also eventually access rights of the var folder and downloader folder

Comment: I checked the access rights they are all fine. and I can't tell if something in var/packages is delited. But as far as I understand it if there is no package in this folder then I also don't see it in the upgrade list. In the meantime I did a manual upgrade that worked. But still interested why this didn't work.